# É possivel retornar de um submenu para menu em Python

Tags: python, menu, submenu

Eu tenho um sistema de menu em Python e gostaria de saber se tipo eu acessar um submenu teria como voltar para o menu principal?

```
print("[1] - Cadastrar Usario")
print("[2] - Lista de Usuarios")
a = input("Qual opção deseja acessar?")
if a == "1":
        b = input("Digite o nome de usuario que quer cadastrar caso contrario, digite CANCELAR")
```

Como faço para retornar pra o menu principal de dentro do input b?

Comment: Você pode criar a função menu() e chamar ela sempre que necessário: no início do seu programa, dentro de um if no input b, etc.

Comment: Ou alguma pergunta [nessa pesquisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+or+%5Bpython-2.x%5D+or+%5Bpython-3.x%5D+is%3Aquestion+menu).